# Cant run debug ruby in rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, rubymine

I do next steps:

1. add breakpoint
2. run - debug - development myproject
3. i open page in my web application, which should work my method with breakpoint

4 open window debug, but nothing information, nothing... only title: connected

Screenshots:

[screenshot 1](http://borowskiy.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Screenshot-2.png) - run - debug - development myproject

[screenshot 2](http://ttp://borowskiy.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Screenshot-3.png) - after open page, whe my code with breakpoint

How me correct run debug? Thanks

Comment: I suggest you using pry gem. Now a days it becomes the father and mother for any debugging.

Comment: Can we have more infos ? Which os do you use ? Tools to debug ?

Comment: i added screenshot. help, please